# How to fix libluajit in architecture x86_64?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x, arm64, luajit

I'm trying to compile my project but see this problem

Problem: [Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64]

**Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYJHT.jpg**

I used: 
+ Cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2 
+ xCode 6.1
+ libluajit newest

Build Setting:

- Valid Architecture: arm64, armv7, armv7s

--> i dont know how to fix it, can you help me to solve this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: run 
file libluajit.a
to see whether library contains required x86_64 slice. If not - you need to compile it for all needed archs

Comment: Hi @AndreiShender,

Do you see http://i.imgur.com/iDOlwMX.png? I used Xcode to build .ipa file but can not add arm64 architectures

Answer (score 1):

i met the same problem as you, solution as below:

**1. download luajit v2.1**

**2. edit build_ios.sh  like this:**

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
LIPO="xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo"
STRIP="xcrun -sdk iphoneos strip"

SRCDIR=$DIR/src
DESTDIR=$DIR/prebuilt/ios
IXCODE=`xcode-select -print-path`
ISDK=$IXCODE/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
INFOPLIST_PATH=$IXCODE/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/version.plist
BUNDLE_ID=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleShortVersionString" "${INFOPLIST_PATH}")
ISDKVER=iPhoneOS${BUNDLE_ID}.sdk

if [ "${ISDKVER}" = "iPhoneOS8.0.sdk" ] || [ "${ISDKVER}" = "iPhoneOS8.1.sdk" ]; then
ISDKP=$IXCODE/usr/bin/
else
ISDKP=$ISDK/usr/bin/
fi

if [ ! -e $ISDKP/ar ]; then 
  sudo cp $ISDK/usr/bin/ar $ISDKP
fi

if [ ! -e $ISDKP/ranlib ]; then
  sudo cp $ISDK/usr/bin/ranlib $ISDKP
fi

if [ ! -e $ISDKP/strip ]; then
  sudo cp $ISDK/usr/bin/strip $ISDKP
fi

rm "$DESTDIR"/*.a
cd $SRCDIR


make clean
ISDKF="-arch armv7 -isysroot $ISDK/SDKs/$ISDKVER"
if [ ${ISDKVER} = "iPhoneOS8.0.sdk" ] || [ ${ISDKVER} = "iPhoneOS8.1.sdk" ]; then
make HOST_CC="gcc -m32 -arch i386" TARGET_FLAGS="$ISDKF" TARGET=arm TARGET_SYS=iOS
else
make HOST_CC="gcc -m32 -arch i386" CROSS=$ISDKP TARGET_FLAGS="$ISDKF" TARGET_SYS=iOS
fi
mv "$SRCDIR"/src/libluajit.a "$DESTDIR"/libluajit-armv7.a

make clean
ISDKF="-arch armv7s -isysroot $ISDK/SDKs/$ISDKVER"
if [ ${ISDKVER} = "iPhoneOS8.0.sdk" ] || [ ${ISDKVER} = "iPhoneOS8.1.sdk" ]; then
make HOST_CC="gcc -m32 -arch i386" TARGET_FLAGS="$ISDKF" TARGET=arm TARGET_SYS=iOS
else
make HOST_CC="gcc -m32 -arch i386" CROSS=$ISDKP TARGET_FLAGS="$ISDKF" TARGET_SYS=iOS
fi
mv "$SRCDIR"/src/libluajit.a "$DESTDIR"/libluajit-armv7s.a

make clean
make CC="gcc -m32 -arch i386" clean all
mv "$SRCDIR"/src/libluajit.a "$DESTDIR"/libluajit-i386.a

make clean
ISDKF="-arch arm64 -isysroot $ISDK/SDKs/$ISDKVER"
make HOST_CC="gcc " CROSS="$ISDKP" TARGET_FLAGS="$ISDKF" TARGET=arm64 TARGET_SYS=iOS
mv "$SRCDIR"/src/libluajit.a "$DESTDIR"/libluajit-arm64.a

make clean
make CC="gcc -m64 -arch x86_64" clean all
mv "$SRCDIR"/src/libluajit.a "$DESTDIR"/libluajit-x86_64.a

$LIPO -create "$DESTDIR"/libluajit-*.a -output "$DESTDIR"/libluajit.a
$STRIP -S "$DESTDIR"/libluajit.a
$LIPO -info "$DESTDIR"/libluajit.a

rm "$DESTDIR"/libluajit-*.a

make clean
```

**3. run this script to create a new 'luajit.a'**

**4. Xcode project add new parameters ' -pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000 ' in 'other linker flags'**

Comment: Thanks, @La Reine J, i will try and tell you result!

Comment: I tried but fail, can you give me step by step, hope you can help me

Comment: Can you give me file libluajit.a after created successfull?

Comment: I can give it to you..  But I am not sure it can work well.  Because I downloaded .a which depends on 2dx.3.x before, but it did not work. So  I have to create a new one depends on my version of 2dx.  If you want to try, please give me your e-mail... I will send it to you

Comment: Plz send to my email:
duc.nguyen0804@gmail.com,

Thank you so much, >:D<

And if you can give me a video about how to build that lib, i will give you a special thanks

Comment: Send it to you.. Please check your mail box.. Thanks.

Comment: @LaReineJ. you must mean luajit 2.0.1 because as of this moment luajit is just 2.0.4. Also I can't make it work following your instructions either. especially step #4

Comment: I was able to download luajit 2.1 alpha but still got the same errors.

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to make it work after cleaning Xcode and build everything again. Thanks for the instructions.